# WCF RIA Services; Classes not being generated on client side

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight, linq, ria

I have the following code  in my domainservice class:

```
public IQueryable<Resources> GetResources()
{
        ResourceToolDataClassesDataContext _context = new 
                                            ResourceToolDataClassesDataContext();
        return _context.Resources
                        .Where(o => (o.EndDate == null 
                               || o.EndDate >= DateTime.Now))
                        .AsQueryable();
}
```

However on the client side I can't seem to access the classes for any of my DataContext, it only works for my entity model.  I've used this code snippet on another project and it worked fine there.. Not sure what is different here.

IF I return a single instance e.g public Resources, it works?? but not with IQueryable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you defined [Key] Attribute on your Resources class?